# Property of a particular type of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

So I have this differential equation:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=p(t)y(1-y)$$
where
$$p(t)=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(2\pi(t-s)\right)\right)^\mu $$

I'm simulating my system first for interval $[0,1]$ for $\mu=0$ and $s=0$, $y(0)=y_0$ and I save the final value $y(1)$. For other values of $s$ and $\mu$, I will "compensate" this diferential equation by multiplying by $C$ on the right hand side:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=Cp(t)y(1-y)$$
such that the final value $y(1)$ remains equal the one obtained with $s=0$ and $\mu=0$, for the same $y_0$.

I did some numerical testing, and I found that for this $p(t)$ the $C$ obtained for some $y_0$ would work for any other $y_0'$ (for the same parameters $s$ and $\mu$ of course). I thought this was a special case, but then after trying with diferent $p(t)$ such as $p(t)=t^{\mu}$ for example, I would get the same result.

In summary, is it possible to show that the value of $C$ is independent of the choosen initial condition for this type of differential equations for any p(t)?

Comment: The key is a change of the independent variable. Replace $y(t)$ with $\bar{y}(s(t))$ and see what you can do with $s$ to simplify the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is valid for any ODE of the form
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=p(t)q(y). \tag{1}
$$
Indeed, dividing both sides of $(1)$ by $q(y)$ and integrating, we obtain
$$
\int_{y(0)}^{y(1)}\frac{dy}{q(y)}=\int_0^{1}p(t)\,dt. \tag{2}
$$
If we replace $p(t)$ with $\tilde{p}(t)$ in $(1)$ and multiply the RHS by a constant $C$ so that $y(0)$ and $y(1)$ are the same for the new ODE, we likewise obtain
$$
\int_{y(0)}^{y(1)}\frac{dy}{q(y)}=C\int_0^{1}\tilde{p}(t)\,dt. \tag{3}
$$
It follows from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that
$$
C=\frac{\int_0^{1}p(t)\,dt}{\int_0^{1}\tilde{p}(t)\,dt}, \tag{4}
$$
so we may conclude that $C$ does not depend on $y(0)$ and $y(1)$ if they are the same for both ODEs.